# How to implement Single-Sign-On on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk, single-sign-on

I'm working on a Windows Phone 7 application with C#.

I want to implement my login page using Facebook account. To do that I'm using codeplex Facebook C# SDK.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ACS for that. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eugeniop/archive/2011/03/24/authentication-in-wp7-client-with-rest-services-part-i.aspx). (answered your other question too)

In short (assuming you are writing a native app):

- Your app (e.g. REST services) trusts ACS. For this you expect a SWT (Simple Web Token) that is issued by ACS
- In your app, you embed a web browser that navigates to the app, to ACS and Facebook
- Once the token negotiation happens in the browser, you extract the SWT and you pass it to the native app
- All subsequent calls to your API include the SWT

If you are writing a "web" app for the phone, then it all just works.

In both scenarios, you would use WIF in your backend. It it is a REST API, you need the OAuth extensions mentioned in the link. If it is a web site, it all works OOB.

Comment: a summary of the link could GREATLY improve the answer.